# What does the parameter "cvid" in Bing search engine stands for?

Tags: bing

As I searching something with Bing and I open the Chrome development tools. Here is the request url:

```
http://cn.bing.com/search?q=%e4%b9%a0%e8%bf%91%e5%b9%b3&go=%e6%8f%90%e4%ba%a4&qs=n&pq=%e4%b9%a0%e8%bf%91%e5%b9%b3&sc=6-6&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=AF49B4165317411D8AFEF30F13BCD108&first=10&FORM=PERE
```

So, what does the parameter "cvid" stands for? It seems if i don't set a `cvid`,i can't get the complete result html in my program.

By the way, the `cvid` is calculated by the browser automaticlly, so how to calculate?

Comment: you ever find out what this is used for?

Answer (score 3):

In the Bing search context, `cvid` represents the JavaScript parameter `ConversationId`.  Bing uses this key to identify your search result collection as its reply to your query, `q`.  Similarly, `pq` is `PartialQuery`.  These and other parameters may also apply to different kinds of searches, such as image or video searches.

Next, `qs` is your query's `SuggestionType`, `sc` shows your `SuggestionCount`, and from the suggestion list (dropped down, if enabled), `sp` shows the `SuggestionPosition` you chose.  In your case, you did not select a suggestion, so `&sp=-1`.  Toward the end of your string, `sk` is the `SkipValue`, because you might skip through your result pages, `first` tells the issuer how many results belong on the first page, and I'll let you figure out what `FORM` means.  ;)

TRY:
Navigate to Bing, conduct a search, choose some options, change your displays, and change some search types.  Next, open file explorer and navigate to your Windows OS equivalent of the following path.

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows
```

Next, you may need to adjust your View temporarily to "Show hidden files, folders, and drives."  View tab > Options > Change... > View tab again, and click the bullet to "Show...".

In File Explorer's Search pane at the upper right, enter ***.js** to find all JavaScript files.  It may point you *several* subfolders deeper, and the folder names may be *hashed*.  Choose a JavaScript file you find interesting, right-click the file, and open it with Notepad, your favorite IDE, or some similar editor.  You should see something akin to this (truncated; may not run independently):

```js
var AutoSuggest,__extends,Bing,sa_inst;(function(n){var t;(function(n){var t,i,r,u,f,e;(function(n){n.User="SRCHHPGUSR"})(t=n.CookieNames||(n.CookieNames={})),function(n){n.AutoSuggest="AS"}(i=n.CrumbNames||(n.CrumbNames={})),function(n){n.CursorPosition="cp";n.ConversationId="cvid";n.SuggestionCount="sc";n.PartialQuery="pq";n.SuggestionPosition="sp";n.SuggestionType="qs";n.PreviewPaneSuggestionType="qsc";n.SkipValue="sk";n.PreviewPaneSkipValue="skc";n.Ghosting="ghc";n.Css="css";n.Count="count";n.DataSet="ds";n.SessionId="sid";n.TimeStamp="qt";n.Query="q";n.ImpressionGuid="ig";n.QFQuery="qry";n.BaseQuery="bq";n.FormCode="form";n.HashedMuid="nclid";n.RequestElToken="elvr";n.ElTokenValue="elv";n.AppId="appid";n.History="history";n.NoHistory="nohs";n.ApiTextDecoration="textdecorations";n.ClientId="clientid";n.Market="mkt";n.Scope="scope";n.CountryCode="cc";n.HomeGeographicRegion="hgr";n.SetLang="setlang";n.ZeroInputSerp="zis"}(r=n.QueryParams||(n.QueryParams={}))
```

I hope that helps *someone*!  :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to find out what this is :)

I'm pretty sure it's an encryption mechanism for bing a la public key cryptography, though I could be wildly wrong. There is another field called `pq` - and `p`'s and `q`'s are used a lot in crypto theory.

The field is **32 nibbles** (e.g. `8D0E519A91024A08B075654D006C0A14`) which equals **128 bits**. This number results in some arithmetic operation with the binary value of your search and bing's private key - thus making url generation quite difficult.